# how to find mask position and size in UIView in ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer, cgrect

I want to get (x,y)position and (width,Height)size of mask from `UIImage` in IOS, I have used `UIImage` as mask like  [image]
I just want to get the frame of the shape from this `UIImage` and I used code for it like

```
thumbImage.layer.mask?.position 
thumbImage.layer.mask?.bounds
```

but I didn't get proper position and frame.

> it is necessary to use this type image for masking no any other options for other image.

Please help me to get proper frame and position of mask in `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the pixels from image and after getting `CGRect` from image compare with your device width and height.

```
- (CGRect)getRectFromImage:(UIImage*)image
{

    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);


    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = 0;

    int xMax = 0;
    int yMax = 0;


    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            unsigned char alphaByte = rawData[(y*bytesPerRow)+(x*bytesPerPixel)+3];
            if (alphaByte > 0) {

            if (xPos == 0) {
                xPos = x;
            }

            if (yPos == 0) {
                yPos = y;
            }
                if (x < xPos) {
                    xPos = x;
                }

                if (y < yPos) {
                    yPos = y;
                }

                if (x > xMax) {
                    xMax = x;
                }

                if (y > yMax) {
                    yMax = y;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"(%i,%i,%i,%i)", xPos, yPos,xMax-xPos,yMax-yPos);


    free(rawData);

    return CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, xMax-xPos, yMax-yPos);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create variable to get size and position like this code:CGPoint Position;
    Position = thumbImage.frame.origin;
    CGSize Size;
    Size = thumbImage.frame.size;

Comment: i want dynamic frame from mask this is just example ,i have lots of diffrent images for masking